# How to catch Control.invoke exception full stacktrace in other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception, invoke

Consider the following:

(1)Top-Catch

```
    void Test()
    {
        Task.Run(async() => 
        {
           try
           {
             while(true)
             {
                string result = await DoSomethingAsync(cancellationToken);
                Invoke(new MethodInvoke(() => 
                {
                    this.label1.Text = result;
                }));
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequest();
             }
           }
           catch(OperationCanceledException)
           {

           }
        });
    }

    //................//
    static void Main()
    {
       Application.UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
       Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
       Application.SetUnhandleExceptionMode(.CatchException);
    }

    void Application_UnhandledException(object exceptionObject)
    {
        if(exceptionObject is Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Default.LogException(exception);
        }
        else if(exceptionObject != null)
        {
            Logger.Default.Log(exceptionObject.ToString());
        }
    }
```

(2)Task-Catch

```
    void Test()
    {
        Task.Run(async() => 
        {
           try
           {
             while(true)
             {
                string result = await DoSomethingAsync(cancellationToken);
                Invoke(new MethodInvoke(() => 
                {
                    DoSomethingUsingControl(result);
                }));
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequest();
             }
           }
           catch(OperationCanceledException)
           {

           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
              Logger.Default.LogException(ex);
           }
        });
    }
```

(3)Invoke-Catch

```
    void Test()
    {
        Task.Run(async() => 
        {
           try
           {
             while(true)
             {
                string result = await DoSomethingAsync(cancellationToken);
                Invoke(new MethodInvoke(() => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                       DoSomethingUsingControl(result);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                      Logger.Default.LogException(ex);
                    }
                }));
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequest();
             }
           }
           catch(OperationCanceledException)
           {

           }
        });
    }
```

only the method, 'Invoke-Catch', in the three methods can catch DoSomethingUsingControl inner exception and full stacktrace.
I know winform UI Thread throw ex.BaseException.

Can only the third method be used to handle exceptions?
Is there any better way?
Because invokes are everywhere.
I looked for a lot of information and questions on the Internet,
and I don't get it.

Comment: Could this page be of any help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library - Although the examples provided on the page aren't related to `.Invoke` calls, the `try/catch` statements seem to be the key to handling Exceptions within `Task` actions / methods.

Comment: Thanks, It makes no difference to me.